# Overload app pool in IIS

Tags: iis-7, application-pool

Our application normally hangs  and we normally take that out of load balancing when business/end users report it.In normal sceanrios we will automatically take node out of load balancing.But in App pool hang scenarios we dont have that privelage.So i am trying to understand each stage of IIS request queue,When i  see more requests in http.sys queue,i will try to take node out of load balancing.this will not be the total case,so i want to test rigorously and monitor performances at each stage.

so for my task to be done,i need to access urls continously to overload app pool and see the way it is serving requests.I tried using tiny get,but my application uses windows authentication,so  its not working,everytime error is access denied.I tried using wcat ,but not able to understand much from it.

Is there any way i can access url continuously or simulate high app pool requests or any suggestions from your experience are more welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have visual studio you can create a load test http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio you can create a load test

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx